# Get Id from HTML by means of Regular-Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

How can I test, whether the Id of an object (e.g. Image , Div or Table ...) is in html-code. 
The ID could be e.g. as follows: id=My_Img_Id or id="My_Img_Id" or id = " My_Img_Id " or id = My_Img_Id

```
var sHTML = '... any Text abc < IMG src="path/myfile.jpg" id="My_Img_Id" style="..." > ... any Text';
var sId = 'My_Img_Id';
var sReg = '<.*? *id*\= *\"*['+sId+' *"*]$.*';
var sRegExp = new RegExp(sReg, "g");
var Result = sRegExp.test( sHTML );
alert( Result );
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: show the full value of `sHTML`

Comment: The HTML-Code is in a tetx file, therefore I cannot use something as follows: $('#My_Img_Id').length

Comment: But you can use the method of @Adil uncle..

Comment: I don't know "the method of @Adil uncle..".
But I think my problem will be resolved by means of Regular-Expression.

Comment: @user3417601 are you trying to extract id through this `'<.*? *id*\= *\"*['+sId+' *"*]$.*';` regex?

Comment: Yes, but it does not work properly :(

Comment: did you want `id=My_Img_Id or id="My_Img_Id" or id = " My_Img_Id " or id = My_Img_Id` to match and stored it to sReg?

Comment: @user3417601 how about this http://regex101.com/r/cV2hG6 ?

Comment: Yes, it will be also ok, but a result as false or true would be also enough (e.g. If the Id is in HTML-Code then do somethig ... else do others ...).

Comment: just implement the above regex in your code.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yeah.. http://regex101.com/r/cV2hG6 your code seems perfectly valid at this moment.. what is he asking for again..?

Comment: The above regex is wrong! It don't work proper. Therefore I am trying to find a better solution/suggestion here.

Comment: The below code snippet will deliver a proper result such as false/true, if the ID matches. The Id could be e.g. as follows: id=My_Img_Id or id="My_Img_Id" or id = " My_Img_Id " or id = My_Img_Id . sReg = '(<.*?[idIdID] *=[" ]*'+sId+')[" ].*?';

Answer (score 2):

First convert the html string to jQuery object then you can use find to get the element from jQuery object. Use the length property if it more then zero then the element with id exists in html string.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vr9xq/)**

```
$(sHTML).find('#' +sId ).length
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if ($(sHTML).find('#My_Img_Id').length) {
    //write your code here
}
```